# Как установить два слушателя для GridView?

Tags: java, android, gridview

Необходимо слушать и касание GridView и узнавать номер позиции.

Номер узнаю так:

```
GridView gv_month;
gv_month.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Log.d("MyLog","day : " + String.valueOf(position)    
    });
```

Касание так:

```
gv_month.setOnTouchListener(new AdapterView.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    switch (v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.gv_month:
                            fromPosition = event.getX();
                        default: break;
                    }
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    switch (v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.gv_month:
                            float toPosition = event.getX();
                            if (fromPosition > toPosition){
                                Log.d("MyLog","LEFT");
                            }
                            else if (fromPosition < toPosition){
                                Log.d("MyLog","RIGHT");
                            }
                            default: break;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Если реализую оба слушателя, то работает только второй. Как совместить?

Comment: Вы в касание используете только `Log.d("MyLog","day : " + String.valueOf(position)` Так почему бы его не поставить после строчки,например, `fromPosition = event.getX();` и передавать туда позицию по `X`. А как вы `X` определяете, также определить `Y`

Comment: GridView имеет каждый раз разное количество ячеек и располагаются на экране иногда по три ячейки в ряду, иногда по 6. В общем сложно будет высчитать на какую ячейку было нажатие используя X и Y. Или я неправильно понял идею с координатами.

Comment: Правильно. Только вам какие координаты нужны? относительно всего экрана или ячейки? По факту, можно ведь высчитывать относительно всего экрана.

Comment: Мне нужно знать номер ячейки которой коснулись. Высчитывать ее, используя координаты, сложно, т.к. количество ячеек всегда разное и располагаются они каждый раз по разному. Одновременно мне надо отслеживать, произошло просто касание или провели по экрану в месте расположения GridView.

Comment: Может [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561010/how-to-use-setonitemclicklistener-and-setontouchlistener-both-in-gridview-case) вам поможет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return true надо заменить на return false, тогда не прерывается обработка касаний

Comment: а ларчик просто открывался :) Спасибо!